# Failed to fetch TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new learning ReactJS. I'm trying to integrate my product list but I've some problem with fecth(). I've tried to work around with it but can't figure out why I encounter this bug.
Here is my code
App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";
import ProductList from './components/productList';

function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <Router>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<ProductList/>}/>
            </Routes>
          </Router>
        </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

productList.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {Table} from "react-bootstrap";

function ProductList() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const fetchInfo = () => {
        return fetch("http://localhost:3001/products", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                accept: 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((d) => setData(d))
    }
    // console.log(data)
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchInfo()
    },[])
    return(
        <div className="col-sm-16 offset-sm-3">
            <Table>
                <tr className="col-sm-4">
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                </tr>
                {
                    data.map((item) => 
                    <tr>
                        <td>item.ID</td>
                        <td>item.Name</td>
                        <td>item.Price</td>
                    </tr>
                    )
                }
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
}
export default ProductList;
```

ERROR:

*Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR
Failed to fetch
TypeError: Failed to fetch
at fetchInfo (http://localhost:3000/main.50ca57794d79a9ad2717.hot-update.js:30:12)
at http://localhost:3000/main.50ca57794d79a9ad2717.hot-update.js:39:5
at commitHookEffectListMount (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30607:30)
at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32100:17)
at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32072:13)
at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32062:11)
at commitPassiveMountEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32052:7)
at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33937:7)
at flushPassiveEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33889:18)
at commitRootImpl (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33848:9)*

Now I'm hoping that I can fetch the API without this error. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Look in the network tab of the devtools to see *why* the fetch failed. Most likely reasons: 1. You don't have anything running on port 3001 of `localhost`. 2. You do, but you're making the request from a different [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) and the response doesn't have [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to relax the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).